# ¿Que puede sustituir el comando time.sleep() de python en windows 10?

Tags: python, windows10

Estoy creando una historia interactiva pero soy nuevo en python. No se cual es el comando que tengo que utilizar en windows 10 a la vista de que el time.sleep() no funciona.

```
def lectura(frase):
    for i in frase:
        punto ='.'
        muestra = ''
        muestra = muestra + i
        print ("\x1b[1;33m" + muestra,end='')
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if i == punto:
            print()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: ¿Cómo que `time.sleep()` no funciona en windows10? ¿Será que olvidaste el `import time`?

Comment: No, no lo olvidé. Por lo visto un programa que use el time sleep en python luego no puede ejecutar ese comando en windows 10 (por lo que estuve googleando).

Comment: Primera noticia de tal cosa. De hecho acabo de probar en mi Windows 10 y no me ha dado ningún problema. ¿Qué error o comportamiento extraño observas tú?

Comment: He añadido la funcion para que la veas. El probema lo da con el primer time.sleep(), porque el segundo si que funciona. La idea es que las letras aparezcan poco a poco y cada vez que el texto llegue a un punto pues comience en una nueva linea.

Comment: Entiendo, el problema no es del sleep, es de que la salida de texto es buffereada. Esto quiere decir que aunque tu programa vaya añadiendo letras a la salida estándar, éstas no se muestran cuando tu programa las emite, sino cuando el operativo decida, lo cual suele ser cuando se completa una línea (o sea, tras el `print()`). Para forzar a que la salida no sea buffereada ejecuta tu programa con `python -u script.py`

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no necesitas quitarle el control al usuario, hay una manera muy fácil de hacer esto: Crear un threading.Timer.

Lo que quieres hacer es tomar la "continuación" de la función, es decir, todo lo que vendría después del time.sleep(), y trasladarlo a una función separada my_function, luego programarla de la siguiente manera:

threading.Timer(60, my_function).start ()
Y al final de mi función, programa un nuevo temporizador con la misma línea de código.

El temporizador es una interfaz y una implementación bastante torpes, pero está integrado en el stdlib. Puedes encontrar alternativas en ActiveState y módulos en PyPI que proporcionan mejores clases que, por ejemplo, ejecutan varios temporizadores en un hilo en lugar de un hilo por temporizador, te permiten programar llamadas recurrentes para que no tenga que reprogramarse, etc. 
Pero para algo que se ejecuta cada 60 segundos, creo que puede estar bien con el temporizador.

Una cosa a tener en cuenta: si el trabajo en segundo plano necesitas tratar con cualquiera de los mismos datos que el usuario está tratando en el REPL, existe la posibilidad de una condición de carrera. A menudo, en un entorno interactivo (especialmente en Python, gracias a la GIL), puedes imponerle al usuario la responsabilidad de no causar ninguna carrera. Si no, necesitarás algún tipo de sincronización.

Pero hay una solución mejor en ese caso de todos modos. Los programas de GUI tienen un bucle de eventos que se ejecuta en un hilo u otro, y casi todos los bucles de eventos que se hayan diseñado tienen una forma de programar un temporizador en ese hilo. Para tkinter, si tiene un identificador para el objeto raíz, simplemente llame a root.after (60000, my_function) en lugar de threading.Timer (60, my_function) .start (), y se ejecutará en el mismo hilo que la GUI, Y sin desperdiciar ningún recurso innecesario.

Comment: Aunque la respuesta es buena, creo que no se ajusta a lo que el usuario necesita. Teniendo en cuenta que como él mismo dice "es nuevo" en python, creo que el nivel de la respuesta es demasiado avanzado. Por otro lado, tampoco hace falta recurrir a programación multihilo para "detener" el proceso un tiempo dado, que es lo que él pedía. El clásico `time.sleep()` funciona, **también en windows**, por lo que quizás habría que averiguar por qué dice que no le funciona, antes de proponer alternativas demasiado complejas para él.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. La verdad es que debería de ir. Pero no funciona, pregunté a un amigo que ya es  más avanzado en ese lenguaje y me dijo que el problema probablemente fuera que con la version 3 de python ya no fuera compatible con windows y que buscara otra funcion que actuase de la misma forma

Answer (score 3):

La función `time.sleep()` no da ningún problema en Windows 10. Sigue siendo perfectamente compatible. Se trataba de un caso de "Problema XY", en el que estás preguntando sobre cómo resolver X, cuando en realidad el problema era Y.

Me explico.

Una vez has mostrado el código de lo que querías hacer, se observa que `time.sleep()` era utilizado para crear una pausa entre letras a la hora de vocar un texto.

El retardo estaba funcionando bien (como podrías comprobar cronometrando el tiempo que tu programa tarda en mostrar el texto, y observando que crecía cuantas más letras debía mostrar), el problema era que, a pesar de ese retardo, el texto salía "de golpe" en cada línea, y no letra a letra.

La razón de ese comportamiento no tiene nada qué ver con `time()` ni con Windows (lo mismo ocurrirá en cualquier otro operativo). Y es que la salida está buffereada, esto es, no se envía directamente a la terminal, sino a un buffer intermedio. Por tanto las letras no se ven en el momento que el programa las "emite", sino en el momento en que el buffer intermedio se envía a la terminal, lo cual por defecto ocurre sólo cada salto de línea.

Una solución es añadir al `print()` el parámetro `flush=True`.

Otra opción es ejecutar el programa pasándole a Python la opción `-u`.

Aparte de eso, ¿por qué en cada iteración del bucle inicializas `muestra` con una cadena vacía para después concatenarle `i`? propongo dejarlo así:

```
def lectura(frase):
    for letra in frase:
        print ("\x1b[1;33m" + letra, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        if letra == ".":
            print()
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Por otro lado, no estoy seguro de que Windows soporte los escapes ANSI para cambio de color...

Comment: Muchas gracias!